# OpenCL, TBB, OpenMP

Tags: multithreading, opencl, openmp, tbb

I have implemented few normal looping applications in OpenMP, TBB and OpenCL. In all these applications, OpeCL gives far better performance than others too when I am only running it on CPU with no specific optimizations done in kernels. OpenMP and TBB gives good performance too but far less than OpenCL, what could be reason for it because these both are CPU specialized frameworks and should gives at least a performance equal to OpenMP/TBB.

My second concern is that when it comes to OpenMP and TBB, OpenMP is always better in performance than TBB in my implementations in which I havent tuned it for a very good optimizations as I am not so expert. Is there a reason that OpenMP is normally better in performance than TBB? Because I think they both or even OpenCL too uses same kind of thread pooling at low level.... Any expert opinions? Thanks

Comment: What is your algorithm? What is your OS and compiler?

Answer (score 4):

One advantage that OpenCL has over TBB and OpenMP is that it can take better advantage of SIMD parallelism in your hardware.  Some OpenCL implementations will run your code such that each work item runs in a SIMD vector lane of the machine, as well as running on separate cores.  Depending on the algorithm, this could provide lots of performance benefits.

C compilers can also take some advantage of SIMD parallelism as well, using auto-vectorization, but the memory aliasing rules in C make it hard for this to work in some cases.  Since OpenCL requires programmers to call out the work items and fence memory accesses explicitly, an OpenCL compiler can be more aggressive.

In the end, it depends on your code.  One could find an algorithm for which any of OpenCL, OpenMP, or TBB are best.

Comment: I am using intel compiler in all cases, so I compiled my all applications using "icc -O0" option to disable auto optimzations by the compiler. So I suppose I stopped compiler from auto-optimizations like SIMD etc, but someone told me OpenCL need "-cl-opt-disable" option in clBuildProgram function to disable OpenCL auto-optimizations; but when I try that, it gives me error as "undefined -cl-opt-disable", I am using latest AMD OpenCL SDK, why I get this problem? and does intel's -O0 option help in disabling OpenCL auto-optimizations?

Comment: If you are using -O0 on the C code, the compiler is certainly not trying to vectorize.  In fact, I wouldn't spend any time worrying about the performance of code compiler with -O0.  It's more interesting to compare the performance of code with compiler oprimizations at -O3.

Comment: @AkhtarAli, you compared OpenCL code to OpenMP and TBB without optimization. That's really silly!

Comment: OpenMP 4 has SIMD support. See spec for details. Intel compilers definitely support this feature now.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCL runtime for CPU and MIC provided by Intel uses TBB under the hood. It's far from just 'thread pooling at low level' since it takes advantage of sophisticated scheduling and partitioning algorithms provided by TBB for better load balance and so better utilization of CPUs.

As for TBB vs. OpenMP. Usually, it comes down to incorrect measurements. For example, TBB has no implicit barrier like in OpenMP, so a warm-up loop is not enough. You have to make sure all the threads are created and this overhead is not included into your measurements. Another example: sometimes, compilers are not able to vectorize the same code with TBB which is vectorized with OpenMP.

Comment: I looked into using TBB instead of OpenMP. The main feature I was looking for was a way to define the thread topology (cores, sockets, logical processors,...) since OpenMP does not have direct support for this but it seems neither does TBB? Additionally, TBB is task based rather than thread based so rather than giving me more low level control it gives less. I don't mean to criticize. I'm wondering if I misunderstand TBB and should consider TBB again.

Comment: TBB provides task_arena and task_scheduler_observer. Having these and a black belt in programming, you can pin worker threads as you want and restrict work distribution to as you want. Actually, these features were driven by OpenCL's fission feature. Thread-based programming is not composable, it's bad for nested algorithms, bad for libraries. TBB often beats OpenMP thanks to better load balancing.

Comment: Better load balancing is a very enticing feature. I think I'll look into TBB again.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCL kernels are compiled for the given hardware. The potential for vendor/hardware specific optimisations is huge.