# OpenMP directives inside functions

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I have a program which simulates movement of entities on a 2D mash. It runs a sequence of operations in several iterations. All of the operations work with the mesh and some of them need thread synchronization of some kind. I have experience with pthreads, there I know what is happening, but this time I have to use OpenMP.

My problem is that I don't know (and I couldn't even find any mentions on the internet) if I can use OpenMP directives in functions. All examples of OpenMP use just one function and all calls to other functions are independent on all threads.
My intention is to create all threads once and than run everything in parallel multiple times. I know that each of the functions will be called number-of-threads times in each iteration; that is desired; the synchronization and work-splitting should be handled inside those functions.

The program crashes often with Segmentation Fault; usually in finishStep function or somewhere in printPopulation. It is impossible to debug with gdb.
An example of a crash (attributes xStart, xEnd are only set when the program starts):

```
0x0000000000401d7d in printPopulations (world=0x607030) at apocalypse.c:210
210             Tile *currentCell = GET_TILE(world, x, y);
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000401d7d in printPopulations (world=0x607030) at apocalypse.c:210
#1  0x0000000000401ef0 in printStatistics (world=0x607030) at apocalypse.c:253
#2  0x0000000000402126 in main._omp_fn () at apocalypse.c:316
#3  0x00007ffff78cef3e in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgomp.so.1
#4  0x00007ffff7475124 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007ffff71a94bd in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) info locals
currentCell = 0x7ffff71360f9 <__GI__IO_do_write+25>
y = 414
humans = 0
x = -1511828487 // this is weird
y = 2
x = 2
humans = 800
```

This is simplified version of my code:

```
World * w = ...;
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(numThreads) default(shared)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
    simulateStep(w);
    finishStep(w);
    printPopulations(w);
    #pragma omp single // this should synchronize everything
    printf("time: %d\n", w->clock);
  }
  cleanup(); // each thread cleans its own threadprivate global variable.
}
```

Simulate step contains two nested for loops. Only one thread should increase the clock counter. Threads will be synchronized at the end of the increment. After that they all will get the same value when accessing world->clock. The mesh is divided into equal parts; each of them is column of full height.

```
void simulateStep(World * world) {
  #pragma omp single
  world->clock++;

  #pragma omp for schedule(static)
  for (int x = world->xStart; x <= world->xEnd; x++) {
    lockColumn(world, x);
    for (int y = world->yStart; y <= world->yEnd; y++) {
      // independent calculation for each tile [x, y]
    }
  }
}
```

Because entities on the mesh move and they could move outside the range, we need to move them back from the borders. Motivation: dedicate at most one thread to each side. If there are more threads, they will wait at the end of sections region. If there are less, then some will run several sections.

```
void finishStep(World * world) {
  #pragma omp sections
  {
    #pragma omp section
    {
      MOVE_BACK(...) // moves the entity on the left border back
    }
    #pragma omp section
    {
      MOVE_BACK(...) // right
    }
    #pragma omp section
    {
      MOVE_BACK(...) // top
    }
    #pragma omp section
    {
      MOVE_BACK(...) // bottom
    }
  }
  // this function basically traverses the world and modifies all tiles.
  // it contains two nested fors which are parallelized like in printPopulation.
  resetWorld(world);
}
```

Print population is. Motivation: we need a function-locale shared variable, therefore humans is static. Only one thread should reset the value. Each thread will count humans in part of the mesh and at the end, their counts will be reduced into the shared variable humans. At the end, one of the threads should print the population count.

```
void printPopulation(World * world) {
  static int humans;
  #pragma omp single
  humans = 0;

  #pragma omp for collapse(2) schedule(guided, 10) reduction(+: humans)
  for (int x = world->xStart; x <= world->xEnd; x++) {
    for (int y = world->yStart; y <= world->yEnd; y++) {
      Tile *currentCell = GET_TILE(world, x, y);
      if (currentCell->entity != NULL)
        humans++;
    }
  }

  #pragma omp single
  printf("Time: %d \tHumans: %4d\n", humans);
}
```

---

Can I use this approach of for, single and sections regions inside functions which are called in parallel? Or can I use them only inside the function where parallel region is defined?

Please try to explain why, I tried to find something in the OpenMP specification but failed. I know that I can use critical region in functions.
Should I replace #pragma omp single with critical region? This way:

```
static int clock; // time of processing
#pragma omp critical(nameOfRegion)
{
  if (clock < world->clock) {
    clock = world->clock;
    // this part will be run only once per each timestamp
  }
}
```

Similarly I could replace sections. Having a loop which would have an array in critical. Each thread would find an unprocessed element and than jump to that section using switch.

But for for-loops, I would have to either divide the range manually, or basically write my own scheduler using locks or critical regions.

Or (the worst case): I have to move parallel region from the main function into all functions where I want to parallelize loops.

Comment: I would rethink how you want to implement this. The way you have it now you have every thread run over all of the outer loop and then for every iteration you run more parallel loops. Is that what your really want to do? Perhaps you can find a way to use `parallel for` only on the outer loop or only use threads inside the outer loop. See this for an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479258/cholesky-decomposition-with-openmp.

Comment: You can see that I have parallel region only around the main loop. All regions inside don't have the keyword parallel - they should just schedule - manage the existing threads.

Comment: Yes, I see that, but that does not change the fact that every thread is running `for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++)`. What happens if you move `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(numThreads) default(shared)` inside `for (int i = 0; i < iters; i++)`?

Comment: If I move the parallel region inside the loop, I still get the same SegFaults. I will probably have to move the parallel region inside each of the functions. By the way, the main loop iterates about 50000 times and there are at least 5 places where parallelization is useful - iteration over the whole mesh of along its border.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I think you need to isolate your problem and debug. It's too complicated now on SO for others to spend the time to figure out. If you could produce a simpler working example (not just a bunch of code fragments) you would probably get more help on SO.