# OpenMP Matrix Optimisation

Tags: performance, optimization, matrix, openmp, parallels

I have a two dimensional matrix that needs to be improved its performance with OpenMP

```
#pragma omp parallel private(i, j, k) num_threads(4)
{
    for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
        #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic, 2) // this line cannot be put before the first loop (i) cause of algorithm
        for(j=i+1; j<N; j++) {
            for(k=i+1; k<N; k++) {
                A[j][k] -= A[i][k]*A[j][i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder that could i improve cache coherence or use task for a speedup?

Thanks !

**Note**: The above code is a part of LU Factorization Algorithm. I want to simplify my question. The following code is the real one that i used:

```
#pragma omp parallel private(i, j, k) num_threads(4)
{
    for(i=0; i<N; i++) {
        #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic, 2) nowait
        for(j=i+1; j<N; j++) {
            A[j][i] = A[j][i]/A[i][i];
        }

        #pragma omp barrier

        #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic, 2) nowait
        for(j=i+1; j<N; j++) {
            for(k=i+1; k<N; k++) {
                A[j][k] -= A[i][k]*A[j][i];
            }
        }

        #pragma omp barrier
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of math operation is this? Is it related to Cholesky decomposition?

Comment: It's LU Decomposition, in fact, the real algorithm doesn't run like that, but i wanna simplify my question.

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479258/cholesky-decomposition-with-openmp/23063655#23063655? Yes you can improve cache coherence. You should use loop tiling. It's very difficult to get the maximum efficiency. If you want to know how see http://www.openblas.net/

Comment: You're right. It's 1.5 times faster than the old one. Thanks !

Comment: Aside from the better fixes above, the two explicit barriers are unnecessary, since there's an implicit barrier at the end of each omp for.

Comment: Because of nowait, i don't know why but when i use nowait, it is faster.